# Selenium webdriver test run speed varies

Tags: automation, selenium-webdriver

I was curious about why does Selenium webdriver run with varying speed. I have noticed it that whenever I run the tests after a gap of 2-3 days the speed is noticeably slow as compared to tests run back to back day after day. The send keys execution is slow, like earlier it was all keys at once in textbox and now its one by one key input. I googled about this but there are no ways to control the speed of webdriver. Any clues about this?

Note:- Environment parameters (Net connectivity, PC free memory etc.) are the same they were when test run was at lightning speed.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you shutting-down(quitting) the driver every time? Sometimes this might have when there are lot of driver process running.

Comment: @Purus I am not doing quit / close after every test run. Even if I close all the instances and start fresh, still the problem persists.